# Edit Asterisk SIP devices using cli / ami

Tags: asterisk

Whether there is a command that provides administration of the SIP devices (add, edit, remove) ?

I can solve it simply overwriting the config files, but command would be better.

ps. How does FreePBX or any onther Asterisk UI do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sir, you guessed in there in the end of your question, you need to write configuration in to the proper place where configuration is stored.

You will not write this in to the daemon while it is running. If you are vaguely familiar with say, how iptables works, and inserting rules while it is running, this is not like that.

You can do this two ways, write it in to flat files, or if you are using what Asterisk experts refer to as realtime, you can write directly to which ever RDMS you prefer, and then Asterisk pulls that configuration from the DB.

It sounds like you want realtime. It sounds like you can easily write to mySQL from your code. You can then take it from there.

Comment: Please don't add self-promotions to your answers; see the [FAQ#promotion].